# ka-kosher legit?

Tags: kashrut-kosher, food

I want to know if anyone knows or anyone can help me determine if:

ka-kosher as presented at [ka-kosher.com](http://www.ka-kosher.com/) is a legit (orthodox) kosher certification.

I noticed the symbol on a bag of frozen organic broccoli, cauliflower and carrots at Costco and as we know organic and broccoli is hard to come by these days (due to all the insects found in them). I've been looking for an organic frozen broccoli that is kosher for a while now but before I indulge I would like to know if anyone can help me determine if the standards are high (as in orthodox) standards with this kashrut agency.

Comment: "legit" in this case means "run by an orthodox jew"?

Comment: for the most part yes. If anyone knows if the standards would match OU and star-k or some other reputable agency on [the crc directory](http://www.crcweb.org/agency_list.php) for broccoli

Comment: I just checked a package of frozen vegetables on it. It says please check for Tolaim right on it along with KA symbol and parve...not sure if its suitable to eat now since broccoli is very difficult to be free of insects and checking might be too difficult...Seems it's legit to me but the burden is on the consumer.

Answer (score 4):

On 22 Nov 2016, I confirmed the Ka-kosher hescher out of Mexico is reliable.  Here's my proof:  I first corresponded with the Company.  The Company said the Star-K certifies their hescher as being legitimate.  STAR-K is a universally accepted kosher certifier.  I called the STAR-K and they confirmed the KA-Kosher products out of Mexico are approved by STAR-K.  Also, per KA's web site, the head masgiach of KA-Kosher is a BMG graduate.  The question I asked Ka-Kosher is why not show this on their web site?  Never heard back on that one.  Anyway, my Rabbi, Rabbi Aaron Gruman of E. Windsor, NJ, verified the legitimacy of the hescher as well.  So between my Rabbi, STAR-K and the masgiach's BMG background, it's safe to say Ka-kosher is fine.

Comment: They are Orthodox, but are not chasidim (overly scrupulous) and I also know that they are in partnership with the star-k at a few locations in Mexico

Comment: I still don't understand all the various kashrus standards for frozen broccoli. As mentioned before, the bag from Costco at the time said to check for Tolaim right on it. I know other brands have said right on the bag "no need for further checking" and they were certified OU-P.  Still, this was an organic brand and the first time I have seen a certified kosher broccoli that was organic. I have no doubt about the legitimacy of it being  a kosher organization but it's disappointing that it did not say what the other brands said in this particular case.

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya  Aaron! Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 4):

It depends on the product.

> I just contacted the Star-K today to ask if the ka-kosher certification
>   is acceptable.  They asked which product - to which I answered that I was asking about 
>   guacamole - they responded it's OK.  I asked does it matter which
>   product, and they responded yes.

So I think it's correct what a previous poster mentioned that the ka-kosher said that the Star-K accepts their hechsher, and what someone said that restaurants under the Star-K serve ka-kosher certified products.  **However**, these are on a product by product basis and you shouldn't infer from their acceptance/serving one product that they'd approve of another.

the Star-K kashrus shailos # is 410-484-4110

Answer (score 3):

Let's address the particular product in question.

[From the Star-K](http://www.star-k.com/kashrus/kk-KosherConsumerMisconsumptions.htm):

> Misconception 5 - Frozen fruits or vegetables bearing kosher certification are pre-checked for *toloyim* [bugs] and are halachically insect-free.
>
> This is not necessarily so.  Some certifications certify that the product does not require any further checking; other organizations may not address the issue, or their standards may be such that the product does not require inspection.  This is a challenging problem for the kosher consumer, because different organizations maintain different standards and some certifications do not address the issue entirely.

From what I'm told from asking some Mexican friends, I get the impression that the hechsher on this product is focused on the ingredients (i.e. it only contains vegetables and wasn't run on a line near non-kosher cheese) and that it's washed well using standard factory processes; it's not like a "Mehadrin" hechsher which is claiming super-duper bug-free. Consult your rabbi as to how much bug-checking must be done on frozen vegetables.

Comment: so is it not run as an orthodox agency?

Comment: I wouldn't say that. As the Star-K said, some Orthodox hechshers are saying "we'll certify the probability of bugs is low enough to not need checking", others are saying "you figure out the bugs yourself."

Comment: where does it say "some Orthodox hechshers"? seems they are just saying some certifications and using cautious wording which could really indicate non-orthodox hechshers.

Comment: After more digging I found the Rabbi who directs it. [R' Chaim Cohen](https://twitter.com/KAKOSHER1/status/477233031090929664). says he worked for OK for 10 years before KA.