# Is Patron Silver tequila kosher for Passover?

Tags: passover, liquor-beer

The white tequila is clear with no additives and is 100% pure agave.

Comment: I believe the legal definition  of "100%" in Mexico with regard to tequila is 51%.

Comment: [Kashrut Department of Maguen David Community in Mexico City](http://www.badatz.ca/kmd) has a contact form. Send them an email as the base kashrus certification doe not require a kosher symbol on it. info@badatz.ca

Comment: Are you asking about a situation where you've purchased it before the holiday, or are you asking about purchasing it during the holiday?

Comment: he may be questioning whether he needs to sell it even if he doesn't plan drinking any on Pesach

Comment: he may be asking if he can serve it to non-jews at his tavern over hol ha-mo'ed.

Comment: according to wikipedia, Yeast is used in the fermentation process: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tequila

Comment: @Loewian: My understanding is that to be called tequilla it must have 51% or more tequila, but if it says 100% agave on it then it is 100% agave

Comment: It could also  be an issue that he has a non-religious Jewish friend who doesn't sell their chametz and whether he'd be allowed to drink it if served it after Pesach.

Answer (score 1):

Interestingly, when you asked the question, it was not certified Kosher for Passover, but now it is. (See [here](https://forward.com/food/397148/patron-tequila-is-going-kosher-for-passover/). The certification is given by [SUPERVISORES EN CALIDAD KOSHER](https://kakosher.com) - their reliability is discussed [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/60473/16354).)

Comment: +1 but this answer might benefit from a brief mention whether pure tequila needs a hechsher or not, for Pesach and otherwise. The OP might think that it does not (and I don't drink tequila so don't know but believe pure vodka doesn't need a hechsher - might or not be right since I also don't drink vodka :->) I do know vodka is not kosher for Pesach though!

Comment: It’s the second; you’re *not* right :) Vodka from grain isn’t KP but when made 100% from potatoes (Chopin), sugarcane (Moses) or corn (Tito’s) it is KP.